# joining schemas from remote server by batching same types

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I am new to apollo server and I am trying really hard to understand how to make remote schemas one huge scheme, I was able to join the schemas and can now query the data, however, I cannot seem to be able to link/resolve the type, my two micro services uses the same type name for those type that are same everywhere with the `pk` being common in all of them only that one has only the `pk` and another one has some extra fields,
my shop schema looks like this

```
type UserType implements Node {
  id: ID!
  shops: [ShopType]
  pk: Int
}
```

and what really matters is the `pk` in this case because it is suppose to join with my auth schema which looks like this

```
type UserType implements Node {
      id: ID!
      username: String
      email: String
      pk: Int
    }
```

with so many other fields, I would like to be able to join the data fields of the two in appolo server since that is where I am merging my two schemas so that when ever I query

```
{
  shops {
    shopOwner {
      username
      email
    }
  }
}
```

then even though the `username` and `email` are not in the first schema, then it can resolve those fields by `pk` from the auth schema

I have used something like this

```
const createNewSchema = async () => {
    const schemas = await createRemoteExecutableSchemas();
    return mergeSchemas({
        schemas,
    });
};
```

to join my schemas so how do I even make the two work together as I desire? thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, I used `stitchschemas` and it looked like this

```
const createNewSchema = async () => {
    const schemas = await createRemoteExecutableSchemas();
    return stitchSchemas({
        subschemas: [
            {
                schema: schemas['shop'],
                merge: {
                    UserType: {
                        entryPoints: [
                            {
                                fieldName: 'shopOwnerById',
                                selectionSet: '{ pk }',
                                args: originalObject => ({ pk: originalObject.pk }),
                            },
                            {
                                fieldName: 'shopById',
                                selectionSet: '{ pk }',
                                args: originalObject => ({ pk: originalObject.pk }),
                            }
                        ]

                    },
                },
            }, {
                schema: schemas['auth'],
                merge: {
                    UserType: {
                        entryPoints: [
                            {
                                fieldName: 'userById',
                                selectionSet: '{ pk }',
                                args: originalObject => ({ pk: originalObject.pk }),
                            },
                        ]

                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        mergeTypes: true,
    });
};
```

in my case just not to confuse anyone I made the `schemas` to be dictionary where each was names by the API it was linking to. also hade to make sure that I made queries for all the `fieldName`'s in my respective enpoints. thanks for taking a looks the guid here https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/stitch-type-merging helped alot